# How to remove a AppBarButton from a CommandBar

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a CommandBar set from XAML:

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar x:Name="MainCommandBar"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Margin="0">

        <!--Toolbar-->
        <AppBarButton x:Name="AppBarButtonScan"
                      Label="Scan"
                      Click="AppBarButton_Click"
                      Icon="Scan" />

        <AppBarButton x:Name="AppBarButtonStop"
                      Label="Stop"
                      Click="AppBarButton_Click"
                      IsEnabled="False"
                      Visibility="Collapsed"
                      Icon="Stop" />

        <AppBarButton x:Name="AppBarButtonPair"
                      Label="Pair"
                      Click="PairButton_Click"
                      IsEnabled="False"
                      Icon="Link" />
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

I would like to remove a button from the code. I tried doing:

```
MainCommandBar.PrimaryCommands.Remove( AppBarButtonScan );
MainCommandBar.InvalidateArrange();
```

and

```
MainCommandBar.PrimaryCommands.Remove( AppBarButtonScan );
MainCommandBar.InvalidateMeasure();
```

and

```
MainCommandBar.PrimaryCommands.Remove( AppBarButtonScan );
MainCommandBar.InvalidateArrange();
MainCommandBar.InvalidateMeasure();
```

and

```
MainCommandBar.PrimaryCommands.Remove( AppBarButtonScan );
MainCommandBar.UpdateLayout();
```

What I see is that the button is getting Collapsed (or removed) but the CommandBar will not update its layout, i.e. there is an empty space left where the removed button was.

Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: Couldn't you just hide it?

Comment: Hide will not fill the space, ie there will be an empty space.

Comment: I have tested it on my site with the code you provided above, and they all works fine, there is no empty space left. So could you share your project or some sample code which can reproduce this issue?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, which brought me here. Has this been resolved?